Unsure whether to keep professional profile or not
So I've been applying for internships/entry-level jobs and I am unsure about whether I should keep my professional profile. I've looked it up, and the general consensus is if you're looking to venture out to other fields unrelated to your major, you should include a professional profile. I feel like because I have little to no work experience there's no point in me including it. Whenever I tailor my professional profile for different roles, I look back and read it, and it's so generic. Would it be better if I were to write a cover letter and remove the professional profile? My academic background is in engineering/tech if it helps.

What do you mean exactly with "a professional profile"?

A reasonable employer fully understands that interns and entry-level people have minimal experience.
How you present yourself - honestly and professionally is helpful. Either way it can't hurt. Not having a profile might be considered lack of initiative.
Keep the logic simple while you are considering this question. There is no magic answer. Risk versus reward. No risk, possible reward.
This is separate from the cover letter and other actions that you can take to promote yourself.

Thank you. I'll go with a professional profile and a cover letter after all.

@raven Good luck.
